# How can I use the CSS pseudo-element :before{ content: '' } to affect an <option> element?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

If I have a list of optons, how can I use the CSS pseudo-element :before{ content: '' } to affect the `<option>`? Below there are three options an I'd like to insert text before each one.

I know this can be done wit javascript / jQuery, but is it possible with CSS?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>

        option::before {
            content: "sandy - "
        }

    </style>


</head>
<body>

<select>
    <option>beach</option>
    <option>field</option>
    <option>carpet</option>
</select>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As mentioned by j08691 in his answer, `:before` is not new to CSS3. It's also called a "pseudo-element" - the "pseudo" tag in the original question is probably there because you couldn't find [pseudo-selector] - that's because that tag got burninated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements actually prepend/append a child node to the element, so this will not work on any element that cannot contain child nodes.

It would be (roughly) the equivalent of doing:

```
<option><span>sandy - </span>beach</option>
```

If you want to update the text value, you will need to use JavaScript.

Comment: The pseudo-elements *may* affect empty elements, too (inserting content before or after the empty content), and `option` elements aren’t even empty.

Comment: The firefox 108 inspector shows that only the inner text of the `<span>` tag is shown; the `<span>` itself is removed.

Answer (score 15):

In 2018, this does work in Chrome, Edge, Firefox, but only if the attribute `size` is specified with a value greater than 1. Safari lacks support.

```css
select {
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  font: 11pt Helvetica;
  
  outline: 0;
}

  select option {
    padding: 8px;
    
     font: 11pt Helvetica;
     
     vertical-align: middle;
  }

  select option::before {
      font-family: FontAwesome, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      content: attr(data-before);

      margin-right: 8px;
  }
 
div + div {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
  <select size="4">
    <option data-before="&#xf26e">500px</option>
    <option data-before="&#xf042">Adjust</option>
    <option data-before="&#xf170">Adn</option>
    <option data-before="&#xf037">Align-center</option>
    <option data-before="&#xf039">Align-justify</option>
    <option data-before="&#xf036">Align-left</option>
    <option data-before="&#xf038">Align-right</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div>
  <select>
    <option data-before="&#xf26e">500px</option>
    <option data-before="&#xf042">Adjust</option>
    <option data-before="&#xf170">Adn</option>
    <option data-before="&#xf037">Align-center</option>
    <option data-before="&#xf039">Align-justify</option>
    <option data-before="&#xf036">Align-left</option>
    <option data-before="&#xf038">Align-right</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that this only works if the options are initially visible (by setting select size attribute). In a select dropdown (without size), the `before` elements do not show.

Answer (score 8):

It appears that for now, you can't. According to the [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content), "This specification does not fully define the interaction of :before and :after with replaced elements (such as IMG in HTML)". Some replaced elements are <img> tags, plugins (<object> tags), and form elements (<button>, <textarea>, <input>, and **<select>** tags).

You can however do this with JavaScript. Oh and BTW, content:, :before, and :after are actually CSS 2.1.

Comment: `:before` is not new to CSS3 - however, the double-colon notation `::before` is. Fable has it that we should continue using the single-colon notation to keep IE8 users sane, but I digress.

Comment: It should also be noted that content generation with the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements *does* work for `<option>` elements, but the replacement won't be reflected in their parent `<select>`s, which makes it rather pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Testing shows that the only browser which does indeed support generating content with :before (or ::before) on OPTION tags is Firefox. All the other big browser DO NOT accept it; this, as someone stated in the linked other question, is standard compliant, as they DO NOT explicitly state how generated content is to be managed in replaced elements such as OPTION.

On the other side, in my view the fact that, when generating content with option::before does work, it does not in any case affect the SELECT tag is correct and VERY USEFUL; the first example that comes to my mind is when you want to show options which are elements of a tree, and so you want to, as to increase UI clarity, indent them based on their level in the tree.

In that case, you surely want to do that ONLY when the option is shown in the opened drop down, while the indent would only be a nuisance if shown in the select when the drop down is closed.