# Content property for option tag not working

Tags: html, css

Edited to make it a non-duplicate:

```
Is there a non-js solution that allows keyboard jumps 
and a tree structure display for the select/option element?

Simple &\nbsp; work in both Firefox(23) and Chrome(28), is there a better solution?
```

I am attempting to create a tree-style select box in css. From what I have been able to [find](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_before.asp), the `:before` tag is supported in IE8+ along with the `content` property. With that being said, I can get the code render as expected in Firefox(23.0), but I cannot get it to render in IE(10) or Chrome(28).

HTML

```html
<select>
    <option class="level0">All</option>
    <option class="level1">Domestic</option>
    <option class="level2">Alabama</option>
    <option class="level1">Foreign</option>
    <option class="level2">Argentina</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```css
.level0:before {
    content:none;
}
.level1:before {
    content:"-";
}
.level2:before {
    content:"--";
}
```

[jsfiddle included](http://jsfiddle.net/bXhqc/)

The reason I want to do it via css is because the client wants to limit javascript on the page and I would like the ability to jump to an option with the keyboard.

Any help to get it working or insight into why it is not working would be appreciated.

**Edit:**After reading the responses in the comments (which were as good as answers explaining why this is [not possible](http://www.red-team-design.com/css-generated-content-replaced-elements)). I decided to use `&nbsp;` characters in pure html to get the desired effect. This allows keyboard jumps in both Firefox and Chrome (although I still havn't found a non-JS solution to get it working in all 3). So - since there are no answers here yet - This is my new question: 
Is there a non-js solution that allows keyboard jumps and a tree structure display for the select/option element?

Comment: You should read this: http://www.red-team-design.com/css-generated-content-replaced-elements

Comment: does your page declare a doctype?  IE8 requires a doctype for both `:before` and `content`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use the CSS pseudo-element :before{ content: '' } to affect an <option> element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198195/how-can-i-use-the-css-pseudo-element-before-content-to-affect-an-option)

Comment: You cannot do it cross browser using only css. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198195/how-can-i-use-the-css-pseudo-element-before-content-to-affect-an-option

Comment: It works for me on Firefox 22

Comment: i know for IE a DOCTYPE must be declared...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use optgroup? Isn't that nested options in a select?

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-optgroup-element

I don't know about the keyboard jumps, but at least you will only have to use JavaScript for the jumps and not for creating the list as well. HTML5 offers the tag, so you should use something native like optgroup before trying to recreate the wheel.

Comment: I looked into optgroup, the problem is the headings are not selectable. In my example above everything needs to be selectable in order for my tree structure to work properly (all, domestic, <state>) are entries in my database and the proper result set for each needs to be displayed.

Comment: I guess I meant use optgroup, and then make the headers work sigh Javascrity, instead of doing the whole thing in Javascript.