# add text content to very first option then apply css style

Tags: php, html, css

I am customizing a part finder extension for Magento, the following is the code I currently have:

```html
<ul class="amfinder-toggle">
  <?php foreach ($this->getFinder()->getDropdowns() as $dropdown): ?>
  <li>
    <div class="dropdown-element amshopby-clearer">
      <select <?php echo $this->getDropdownAttributes($dropdown)?>">

      
        <option>                        
          Select <?php echo $this->__($this->htmlEscape($dropdown->getName())) ?>
        </option> 
          <?php foreach($this->getDropdownValues($dropdown) as $v): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $v['value'] ?>"<?php if ($v['selected']):?>selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
          <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($v['label']) ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach ?>

    
       </select>
    </div>
  </li>
  <?php endforeach ?>
<ul>
```

HTML OUTPUT:

```html
<ul class="amfinder-toggle">
    <li>
  <div class="dropdown-element amshopby-clearer">
   <select name="finder[56]" id="finder-3--56" "="">
    
    <option>Select Year</option> 
    <option value="0">Please Select ... </option>
    
    <option value="13">1989</option>
    <option value="18">1990</option>
    <option value="19">1991</option>
    <option value="20">1992</option>
    
    
   </select>
  </div>
    </li>
    <li>
  <div class="dropdown-element amshopby-clearer">
   <select name="finder[57]" id="finder-3--57" disabled="disabled" "="">
    <option>Select Make</option> 
   </select>
  </div>
    </li>
 <li>
  <div class="dropdown-element amshopby-clearer">
   <select name="finder[58]" id="finder-3--58" disabled="disabled" "=""> 
    <option>Select Model</option> 
   </select>
  </div>
 </li>
                    
</ul>
```

I have three 3 `<li>` and `<select>`. The design is to have viewers to select the drop down filter in sequence; therefore we need to add number 1,2 and 3 to very first option inside 3 `<select>` as the image shows below.
[image]

I learn the fact that we could not do this through CSS.
How do we add numbers 1,2 and 3 respectively into each `<select>` in Javascript?

Comment: please add your html output here! not php. make a inspect element and copy rendered html in your browser. and also your css too!

Comment: does the last image work ?

Comment: No i mean copy that html and paste here! instead of your php code. I want to see your real output, something when you run snipped see your html like first image that included.

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child ?

Comment: Do you need all the <li> content or just one of them?

Comment: @Mike I tried this but it doesnot work `ul.amfinder-toggle li div select option:first-child:before { content: "1";  }`. Even if it does work, it will add "1" to all 3 `<select>`. I need number 1,2 and 3 respectively.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible with CSS because [you can't use  `:before` on an `option` element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198195/how-can-i-use-the-css-pseudo-element-before-content-to-affect-an-option). However if it *were* possible you could use [counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters). Why not just do this with PHP?

Comment: You cannot style options. I'd suggest simulating this with a `<ul>` button drop down

Comment: @OliverQueen You can style options. You just can't use `:before` or `:after`. Changing the `color` or basic things like that work just fine.

Comment: @Mike - got a fiddle? I've never seen it done, not to the extent OP wants.

Comment: @OliverQueen In fact I happened to have one that I was using to get this to work. Ignore the unrelated stuff: https://jsfiddle.net/3ff5x3up/

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I was meaning the actual option element. It would have made my life 123434x easier if it were possible about 2 months ago lol

Comment: @OliverQueen I did style the actual option element red.

Comment: @Mike well, it must not work in Firefox then

Comment: @OliverQueen Actually it works for me with Firefox 43. Just make sure to move your mouse over one of the other options since the first one is selected so you therefore can't see the red text. Not only that, but the `option:before` also works in Firefox, but not Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Floated a span over select. CSS + jQuery Solution.

```js
var openSelect = function(selector){
     var element = $(selector)[0], worked = false;
    if (document.createEvent) { // all browsers
        var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
        e.initMouseEvent("mousedown", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        worked = element.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else if (element.fireEvent) { // ie
        worked = element.fireEvent("onmousedown");
    }
    if (!worked) { // unknown browser / error
        alert("It didn't worked in your browser.");
    }   
}

$('.title').click(function(){
  
  var sel = $(this).next('select');
  sel.click();
  openSelect( sel );

});

$('.select').click(function(){
  
  var curval = $(this).val();
  if(curval === '')
  {
   $(this).find('option').eq(0).hide();
  }
  else
  {
   $(this).find('option').eq(0).show();
  }
});


$('.select').change(function(){
  var curval = $(this).val();
  if(curval != '')
  {
   $(this).prev('span').hide();
  }
  else
  {
   $(this).prev('span').show();  
  }
  
});
```

```css
ul{
   list-style: none; 
}

ul li{
    display: inline-block; 
}

.dropdown-element{
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
}

.title{
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: default;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
}

.select{
   height: 30px;
   width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="amfinder-toggle">
    <li>
  <div class="dropdown-element amshopby-clearer">
            <span class='title'> <span class="badge">1</span> Select Year </span>
   <select name="finder[56]" class='select' id="finder-3--56" "="">
    
    <option value="">Select Year</option>
    
    <option value="13">1989</option>
    <option value="18">1990</option>
    <option value="19">1991</option>
    <option value="20">1992</option>
    <option value="21">1993</option>
    <option value="22">1994</option>
    <option value="23">1995</option>
    <option value="24">1996</option>
    
   </select>
  </div>
    </li>
    <li>
  <div class="dropdown-element amshopby-clearer">
            <span class='title'> <span class="badge">2</span> Select Make </span>
   <select name="finder[57]" class='select' id="finder-3--57" disabled="disabled" "="">
    <option value=""> </option> 
   </select>
  </div>
    </li>
 <li>
  <div class="dropdown-element amshopby-clearer">
            <span class='title'> <span class="badge">3</span> Select Model </span>
   <select name="finder[58]" class='select' id="finder-3--58" disabled="disabled" "="">
    <option value=""> </option> 
   </select>
  </div>
 </li>
                    
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you but it is the phtml that I am working with instead of html. do you know how do we incorporate this?