# Add image into DropDownList for each items

Tags: html, css, image, drop-down-menu

I tried to add images into DropDownList for each items in it, using only HTML and CSS. Here is my code, but it doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

select option[value="en"]::before { content: url("https://www.countryflags.io/gb/flat/24.png"); }
select option[value="vn"]::before { content: url("https://www.countryflags.io/vn/flat/24.png"); }
select option[value="th"]::before { content: url("https://www.countryflags.io/th/flat/24.png"); }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<select>
 <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="vn">Vietnamese</option>
    <option value="th">Thai</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Write three backticks ` before and after your code to format your code correctly. You can see more formatting tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: @FrankVel Thank you so much for the tip, i have updated my post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198195/how-can-i-use-the-css-pseudo-element-before-content-to-affect-an-option

Comment: that solution only partially solved my problem, i think i must use Javascript/Jquery instead. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue by using minimal jquery: the [ms-Dropdown](https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown) makes the job a lot of easier. 
Simply set the the flag image as the title of the select option, and style the width/image height as appropriate. After adding the plugin, only one line of code is required:

```
$("body select").msDropDown(); /* to trigger the function. Adjust as necessary (you might not want to use it on all of the selects in the body*/
```

[Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/enfk658s/)

```
#flags {
  width: 100px;
}

img {
  max-height: 30px;
}

<script src="http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/js/msdropdown/jquery.dd.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/css/msdropdown/dd.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<select name="flags" id="flags">
  <option selected value="English" title="https://www.countryflags.io/gb/flat/24.png"></option>
  <option value="Vietmanese" title="https://www.countryflags.io/vn/flat/24.png"></option>
  <option class="pic" value="Thao" title="https://www.countryflags.io/th/flat/24.png"></option>
</select>
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/enfk658s/)

Comment: @MinhTran Happy to help 

Answer (score 0):

`option[value="English"]` only captures tags with the given attribute, so you should use `<option value="English>English</option>`.

You should also use the `::before` (or `::after`) pseudo-selector, so you don't overwrite the content of the `<option>` element.

As in the linked response, this doesn't work for `<option>` elements unless you set the `size` attribute for `select` to something other than `1`. `<select size="3">` might work, depending on what you want.

Comment: yes, i have tried using the solution with the size="3", it works. But it doesn't work in the way i want, it is no longer a dropdownlist anymore, so i think i must find another solutions. Thank you!