# tickmark not appearing in option dropdown in angular

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to apply a tickmark before a default item in the option dropdown of my angular application. Its  the name steven as shown in this example. How do I achieve that

For some reason it does not seem to apply

I have created a stackblitz to reproduce the issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qac8ae?file=src/app/app.component.html

markup

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="select-wrapper-row">
      <select formControlName="name">
        <option value="">-- Select an option --</option>
        <option
          *ngFor="let item of nameList$ | async"
          [ngClass]="{ checkmark: item.isAlive == true }"
          [selected]="item.isAlive"
        >
          {{ item.name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.checkmark:before {
  content: 'L';
  font-family: arial;
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  color: white;
  height: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.6em;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a StackBlitz example - much easier to get help that way.

Comment: I have added a stackblitz example #dopoto

Comment: Have you investigated if the native html select actually allows you to do this?

Comment: I tried putting the styles in native select css. Not sure if you meant that

Comment: I had come across this link . The main difference that see here is that its is using material option buttons https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-kzzdmu?file=styles.css

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get your stackblitz running.

> **Error in ~/src/main.ts**
> ngcc failed to run on @angular/material@12.0.6.

But the solution can be demonstrated using simple html snippet:

```css
body {
  width: 50vw;
}

div {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted green;
}

.checkmark {
  /* without this checkmark will not be 
      placed relative to the item */
  position: relative;
}

.checkmark:before {
  content: 'L';
  font-family: arial;
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  /* unless your background is dark don't use white as text color */
  color: white;
  height: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.6em;
  text-align: center;
  /* if you want it on left side then remove this*/
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.change1::before {
  color: green;
}

.change2::before {
  position: static;
}

.checkmarkFixed:before {
  content: 'L';
  font-family: arial;
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  color: green;
  height: 1em;
  margin-right: 0.6em;
  text-align: center;
}

select {
  width: 100px;
}

option:checked {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class='checkmark'>Your code: not working</div>
<div class='checkmark change1'>Correction 1</div>
<div class='checkmark change1 change2'>Correction 2</div>
<div class='checkmarkFixed'>Fixed</div>

<select size=5>
  <option value="1" class='checkmark change1'>One</option>
  <option value="3" class='checkmark change1 change2'>Two</option>
  <option value="2" class="checkmarkFixed">Three</option>
  <option value="4" selected>Four</option>
  <option value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

- you are choosing white as color for thickmark. Unless the background is dark it won't be visible.
- if you want it on left of the item then don't use `position:absolute`.
- if you use `position:absolute` then add `.checkmark` rule as shown above.

I have deliberately created separate .change1 and .change2 classes to show you what can be changed to fixe the issue. You can have these changes in one single rule like `.checkmarkFixed:before`

Comment: Would this work on `option` elements as well?

Comment: Yeah it does work if the `size` > 1 :(   https://stackoverflow.com/a/52985450/15273968

Answer (score 0):

`::before` and `::after` are pseudo-elements that actually append a child node to the element, so they will not work on any element that cannot contain child nodes - I.E. `option`.

You could alternatively use a component such as [ng-select](https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/templates), that has this functionality built-in.

Comment: So what you are trying to tell that there is no way that css can be applied on the mark up that I have shared to achieve a tick mark . Is that correct ?

Comment: Some hacks might be possible - see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=select+option+image&searchOn=3. But the option element in particular is restrictive about accepting pseudo-selectors such as ::before or ::after, using advanced styling or adding other HTML elements inside it. A custom implementation that has the look-and-feel of a select element is the way to go here, I think. And ng-select might be the quickest way for you to achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Ive refactored things abit. Here stackblitz example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bbnkfufile=src/app/app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-select placeholder="select" formControlName="title">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let item of nameList$ | async" [value]="item">
      <div class="option-wrapper">
        <span>
          {{ item.name }}
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="item.isAlive" class="checkmark"></span>
      </div>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</form>
```

Css

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}


.option-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.checkmark:before {
  content: 'L';
  font-family: arial;
  -ms-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg);
  transform: scaleX(-1) rotate(-35deg);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1 em;
  color: black;
  height: 1 em;
}

.mat-option {
  width: calc(100vw - 50px);
}
```