# PHP Adding an Icons in a <select, Each <option value=""> has a different icon

Tags: php, css

PHP Adding an Icons in a <select,
Each  has a different icon

Example:

```
<option value="77"> category name </option>
<option value="92"> category name </option>
<option value="93"> category name </option>
```

this code

```
        if($params->get('show_cat','1')==1 && count($categories)){  ?>
    <div class="search_cats djcf_se_row">
     <?php if($params->get('show_cat_label','0')==1){ ?>
        <label><?php echo JText::_('MOD_CLASSIFIEDS_SEARCH_CATEGORY_LABEL'); ?></label>
     <?php } ?> 
        <?php 
                if($params->get('cat_select_type','0')==1){
                    $cat_sel = '<select  class="inputbox" id="se'.$module->id.'_cat_0" name="se_cats[]" onchange="se'.$module->id.'_getFields(this.value);"><option value="">'.JText::_('COM_CLASSIFIEDS_PLEASE_SELECT_CATEGORY').'</option>';
                    foreach($categories as $cat){ 
                        $c_name = str_ireplace("'", "&apos;", $cat->name);
                        for($lev=0;$lev<$cat->level;$lev++){
                            $c_name ="- ".$c_name;
                        }                       
                        $cat_sel .= '<option value="'.$cat->id.'">'.$c_name.'</option>';
                    }
                    $cat_sel .= '</select>';
                    echo $cat_sel;
                }else{
                    $cat_sel = '<select  class="inputbox" id="se'.$module->id.'_cat_0" name="se_cats[]" onchange="se'.$module->id.'_new_cat(0,this.value,new Array());se'.$module->id.'_getFields(this.value);"><option value="">'.JText::_('COM_CLASSIFIEDS_PLEASE_SELECT_CATEGORY').'</option>';
                    foreach($categories[0] as $cat){
                        $cat_sel .= '<option value="'.$cat->id.'">'.str_ireplace("'", "&apos;", $cat->name).'</option>';
                    }   
                    $cat_sel .= '</select>';
                    echo $cat_sel;
                }                   
                ?>
```

Screenshot describing what I mean
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3bWW.png

Comment: What is your intended outcome?

Comment: Screenshot describing what I mean  https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3bWW.png

Comment: I mean do you want each icon to be the same?

Comment: Yes each <option> has a different icon

Comment: What do you see now when you run this code? Are the icons now all the same or ...?

Comment: It appears like this
https://prnt.sc/23y8g4b
https://prnt.sc/23y8lux

Comment: You can't add icon in the select > option element. Answers are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237807/can-i-use-html-tags-in-the-options-for-select-elements) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198195/how-can-i-use-the-css-pseudo-element-before-content-to-affect-an-option). You may use JS like [**Select2**](https://select2.org/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use the CSS pseudo-element :before{ content: '' } to affect an <option> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198195/how-can-i-use-the-css-pseudo-element-before-content-to-affect-an-option)